# Are blisters first time wearing soccer cleats normal, or does it mean bad shoes?

Tags: football, equipment

I played soccer last saturday for the first time in a loooong time. We played for two hours. The day after, I couldn't walk because of my legs .... but my feet were fine. I played in regular sneakers.

This saturday we played again, and I had bought some soccer cleats for the first time in my life. I felt they were maybe slightly thight, but not overly much, and I was told that's how they are supposed to feel anyways.

Now, I have blisters on both feet, and I got them after already an hour of playing today.

Question:

Is this an indication of bad cleats/size and I should get new ones, or is this just how it is the first time you wear cleats and my feet just need time to get used to it?

Answer (score 2):

Blisters on your feet can be caused by several reasons, but mostly they are caused by wearing the wrong shoe size or not wearing them in properly.

When buying new shoes they must not be too tight. They should fit well already in the store. Also if they're too big and your foot is slipping in them that's almost guaranteed a blister.

And before actually playing with them it is necessary to wear them in. It also helps to wear thicker socks to avoid blisters and with some materials it is easier to wear them in when they're wet (wet leather is softer and the shoe will fit easier).

Answer (score 2):

Blisters happen when your shoes don't fit you well. You can get some Blister balm to heal your blister.

**To prevent happening to them again:**

1. Get yourself antiperspirants(not deodorants) and spray it on your
   feet, let it dry and then wear your new shoe.
2. Before heading to the ground for playing, first wear your shoes in
   the house and try to locate your trouble areas and wear paddings in
   your feet where you fill discomfort.

Or you can purchase new shoes; you can go for ***Cowhide leather shoes*** if you want super protection, durability, and water resistant.

If you want high tensile strength and the ability to mold perfectly around your feet go for ***kangaroo leather***.

Whatever shoes you buy, make sure they fit you properly and don't promote excessive sweating along the foot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't played in a "long" time, you're feet were probably not ready along with having new shoes. Some socks are very rough on the inside, so one strategy to prevent this from happening again is to wear two pairs of socks: one pair inside out and then another pair over them the normal way. It gets rid of the roughness and also may fill in any spaces between the shoe and your foot where it's not fitting well.